# Conditionally capturing pre-determined text in one field based on multiple choice selection in another field in REDCap

Tags: conditional-statements, survey, redcap

**Problem:** How can you capture a pre-determined or static *text* value based on what choice a user makes from a multiple choice menu on a survey?

**Example:** Suppose you have the following basic setup:

[image]

I have four *text* statements that correspond to options 1-4 (e.g., "Statement corresponding to Option 1", "Statement corresponding to Option 2", etc.). If the user chooses, say, Option 1 from the `sample_options` field, then I would like to capture the text value of the pre-prepared statement in the `option_statement` field. The user *should not* be able to alter the captured text statement (e.g., maybe hide the field using the `@HIDDEN` action tag).

**Attempt:** It seemed like this might be a problem that could be resolved with action tags, namely the `@DEFAULT` one, but I have been unable to do this. I also thought about trying to use a calculated field instead of a text field for `option_statement`, but calculated fields must return numeric values:

[image]

This seems like a problem that should be somewhat straightforward to tackle, but I have been baffled by just how hard it seems to be to simply capture static text in one field based on a user's selection in another field.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, you want to select a text string from a list of (in this case) 4 options, depending on the user selecting a choice from a radio/dropdown?

Probably the easiest method is to use `@CALCTEXT` (if you are on a sufficiently recent version), which allows you to conditionally populate a text field, i.e.:

```
@CALCTEXT(
    if([sample_options] = 1, "This is the label for option 1",
        if([sample_options] = 2, "This is the label for option 2",
            if([sample_options] = 3, "This is the label for option 3",
                if([sample_options] = 4, "This is the label for option 4", "This is an else value")
            )
        )
    )
)
```

But if you do not have @CALCTEXT available to you, you can do this with a `@DEFAULT`, by constructing another radio field (`@HIDDEN` if you like) on a separate page or instrument (as `@DEFAULT` needs the value to exist in the database on page load, and so does not work dynamically on the page), with your four labels as the options *with the same choice codes as your* `[sample_choices]` *field*. For example:

```
1,This is the label for option 1
2,This is the label for option 2
3,This is the label for option 3
4,This is the label for option 4
```

And annotate it with:

```
@DEFAULT='[sample_choice]'
```

Thus if a user selects 3 for `[sample_choice]` and proceeds to the page or instrument that has the label field, the `@DEFAULT` tag will automatically select choice 3 from the label field, which can then be stored in the dataset and piped into an email, onto the page, or whatever.